# visual studio keyboard shortcut for error description

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

So i have the following c# code snippet:

```
var accountModel = new AccountModel
{
    Email = "iDontExist@gmail.com"
}
```

If you notice carefully you will notice i am missing " ; "

Here is what happens when i hover over the little red squiggly line:

[image]

My question is: How can i show the " ; expected " by using the keyboard and without 
hovering over the squiggly line with the cursor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> and the <kbd>E</kbd> to view the Error List window (default out-of-the-box keyboard config).

I don't think there's a way to show the tooltip without the mousepointer.

Comment: Thanks, It will do until i find a better solution :)

Answer (score 21):

Visual Studio 2015

<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`K`</kbd>, <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`I`</kbd>

Hold down Windows Ctrl Key, keypress K and then keypress I

Comment: what is the name of this action in case those shortcut have been changed?

Comment: @WillHardwick-Smith Edit->QuickInfo

Comment: This should the accepted answer, The currently accepted one is a good shortcut to know, but this is what OP was searching for.